# How to extend the doctrine entity to be working with API platform

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have a case when I want to separate the doctrine entity with API platform annotations.
The main problem is that I'm able to create a resource and it seems ok, but it's not saved in the database. It seems like I need to add one more thing, but have no idea what to put in here.

The mapping is correct, database up to date...

#### Entity class:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Entity;

use Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface;

class Example
{
    /**
     * @var UuidInterface
     */
    protected $uuid;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

#### Entity mapping:

```
<doctrine-mapping
    xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping https://raw.github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/master/doctrine-mapping.xsd"
>
    <entity name="Entity\Example" table="examples">
        <id name="uuid" type="uuid" column="uuid" />
        <field name="name" type="string" column="name" />
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

#### Api Platform class

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ApiPlatform;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Entity\Example as EntityExample;
use Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 */
class Example extends EntityExample
{
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     * @var UuidInterface
     */
    protected $uuid;

    /**
     * @return UuidInterface
     */
    public function getUuid() : UuidInterface
    {
        return $this->uuid;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() : string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param UuidInterface $uuid
     */
    public function setUuid(UuidInterface $uuid) : void
    {
        $this->uuid = $uuid;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name) : void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the XML stored? Have you configured doctrine mappings so it reads that file?

Comment: Yes, the mappings are fine. They are validated, and i can create and save entity instance when create own CRUD system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml there usually is the following configuration:

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
```

If apip did find your resource it will probably be something like:

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/ApiPlatform']
```

But in order to find your entities and their mappings it should be like:

```
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths: 
      - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
      - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Resources/config/doctrine'
      - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/ApiPlatform'
```

The actual folder where doctrine looks for the mappings could be different, look in api/config/packages/doctrine.yaml
or whereever doctrine is configured.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Example class is missing the `$name` property. 
Add `private $name;` after $uuid, unless EntityExample has that protected/public property.

Your ApiResource() annotated class seems to have no serialization groups annotations, to any of the properties. 
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ApiPlatform;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Entity\Example as EntityExample;
use Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface;

/**
  * @ApiResource(
  *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}},
  *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write"}}
  * )
 */
class Example extends EntityExample
{
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     * @var UuidInterface
     */
    protected $uuid;

    /**
     * @Groups({"read", "write"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return UuidInterface
     */
    public function getUuid() : UuidInterface
    {
        return $this->uuid;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     * @Groups({"read", "write"})
     */
    public function getName() : string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param UuidInterface $uuid
     */
    public function setUuid(UuidInterface $uuid) : void
    {
        $this->uuid = $uuid;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name) : void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use serialization groups, annotate the entity with `@ApiResource` (i.e. and not `ApiResource()`).

Comment: Yes, it has protected $name property which is pointed in code section of Example class